# List all contacts in sub-categories of parent category

Tags: contact

I would like to display list of contacts from sub-categories in a category like this:

**Main Category name**:

```
 Sub-Category 1 name:
     Contact 1 details
     Contact 2 details etc
 Sub-category 2 name:
     Contact 3 details
     Contact 4 details etc
```

I cannot see a way of displaying all contacts in the sub-categories on the same page.

Somebody suggested creating a contact module for each sub-category and include these in an article. This sounds like a great idea but I do not have Contacts as an option when creating a new module so how can I create a module for the contact sub-category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create the module independently, then either use the Joomla load module or Regular Labs Modules Anywhere to load within the article:

[How do you put a module inside an article?](https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article%3F)

[How to Use {loadposition} and {loadmodule} in Joomla](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/loadposition-loadmodule)

[Modules Anywhere](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/modulesanywhere)

For the module itself, here is a link to modules listed in the Contact Details category:
https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/?searchall=&filter%5Btags%5D%5B%5D=&filter%5Bcore_catid%5D=198&filter%5Bincludes%5D=mod&dir=DESC&limitstart=&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1

Looking through them quickly, it looks like the JoomlaXTC Contact Wall would do it.  It has a lot of features you don't need, but looking at the options, it lets you adjust the module template.
https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/contact-details/contact-wall/
http://demo.joomlaxtc.com/?extension=contactwall

The other option would be to do it similarly but with component views instead of separate modules.  Take a look at Components Anywhere, also by RegularLabs.  I am a big fan of all their extensions because they just work, without drama:
https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/componentsanywhere

Comment: The problem is I can't see how to create a module of type contacts in the first place.  The options for new module does not incude contacts.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for looking. I have had a look at these extensions already and none are suitable I think. The one you suggested looks overly complicated, is paid download only and does not implement the Joomla update system.  I have created a separate menu item for each category of contacts for now. Not ideal but will have to do.

Comment: add other option to answer